# Ubuntu fails to boot with kernel 5.4, ic2 timeout error

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, kernel

I have a laptop running ubuntu 18.04 that suddenly refused to boot, showing these errors, white on a black screen:

```
nvidia-gpu ic2 timeout error e0000000
i2c_transfer failed -110
ucsi_ccg_init failed -110
```

I can start the laptop by pressing ESC early on and using advanced options in grub to start with kernel 5.3, only kernel 5.4 fails to boot. Everything seems normal on kernel 5.3.

I'd like to not be dependent to time pressing ESC corretly to start the machine however, how do I fix this?

The nvidia driver installed is 440.100, the laptop has a rtx 2060.

There now are disk errors, as requested below, here is the SMART data of both system disks, taken via nvme-cli, as these are nvme ssds.

```
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0n1 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                    : 0
temperature                         : 46 C
available_spare                     : 100%
available_spare_threshold           : 10%
percentage_used                     : 0%
data_units_read                     : 1143251
data_units_written                  : 1738042
host_read_commands                  : 16077525
host_write_commands                 : 34088922
controller_busy_time                : 180
power_cycles                        : 261
power_on_hours                      : 236
unsafe_shutdowns                    : 31
media_errors                        : 0
num_err_log_entries                 : 249
Warning Temperature Time            : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
Temperature Sensor 1                : 46 C
Temperature Sensor 2                : 45 C
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count   : 0
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count   : 0
Thermal Management T1 Total Time    : 0
Thermal Management T2 Total Time    : 0

Smart Log for NVME device:nvme1n1 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                    : 0
temperature                         : 43 C
available_spare                     : 100%
available_spare_threshold           : 10%
percentage_used                     : 0%
data_units_read                     : 244690
data_units_written                  : 227390
host_read_commands                  : 10047273
host_write_commands                 : 1546361
controller_busy_time                : 23
power_cycles                        : 261
power_on_hours                      : 17
unsafe_shutdowns                    : 32
media_errors                        : 0
num_err_log_entries                 : 249
Warning Temperature Time            : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
Temperature Sensor 1                : 43 C
Temperature Sensor 2                : 41 C
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count   : 0
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count   : 0
Thermal Management T1 Total Time    : 0
Thermal Management T2 Total Time    : 0
```

Comment: What is the Nvidia driver version?

Comment: version 440.100

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Sorry, work has been busy, so I'll probably look into this at the end of the week when I don't risk breaking stuff on my work laptop even more...

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

In `terminal`, do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to determine your current BIOS version, and then go to the laptop manufacturer's web site to see if there's a newer BIOS available.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Nvidia**

You have Nvidia version 440.100. There's a newer Nvidia driver available for Nvidia RTX 2060.

Either open `Software & Updates` and see if driver 450.57 is available there, or go to https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/ to download that version there.

Direct download at https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/162107/

Note: Have good backups before updating the Nvidia driver.

**Update #1:**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: It did not offer 450, so I tried 435, which worked and the system booted fine. However when I then tried to shutdown, it hanged, I had to force it off. Now it hangs on some file system error, fsck only produces more error messages. I'll wipe the machine.

Comment: @Cola_Colin Don't wipe the machine yet. Do Update #1 in my answer. Edit your question and show me screenshots of the `Disks` app SMART DATA scrollable window. Nvidia 450.57 is there, and also via the direct download link I provided.

Comment: A wipe was planned for next month anyway for a reconfiguration to an encrypted disc, so I will just move ahead with that earlier. The laptop came with a "reset to factory configuration"-stick, so that hopefully will be easy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You (we) should still look at the SMART DATA, as your disk may be failing, and moving to encryption may become a disaster.

Comment: I've posted SMART data of both SSDs in the laptop. Anything to worry about?

Comment: I don't see anything alarming there, but it's not quite the same data as from the `Disks` SMART DATA. Have you checked for firmware updates for the NVMe's? Show me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of the laptop. Did you find Nvidia 450.57?

Comment: I think I'll just go ahead with resetting the machine now, I do have a backup of all work data on the system, so if there is a hardware error I can just go to the manufacturer of the system, it is in warranty and the reset stuff is an official tool by them.

Comment: Well, I'd recommend not doing that yet, but you'll have to decide for yourself, of course. I'd be checking the BIOS, NVMe firmware, and Nvidia driver... if it was me. Moving to encryption will only complicate things. Please keep me posted.

Comment: The installation went through with no issues. Encryption or not is sadly not my decision, customers have decided to put up data protection requirements for mobile devices. The installation script ends up with nvidia 440 again, but that works just fine now. Nvidia drivers on ubuntu or an endless source of trouble...